# TastyPie / RestKit 501 Not Implemented

Tags: ios, django, restkit, tastypie

I'm using tastypie for a REST interface in django, from Xcode I can call the server and get data successfully using RestKit however I cannot POST data. I know it's hitting the right area as I had a 401 then turned on `authentication()` in django and that problem was solved, now I'm receiving a `501 Not Implemented` Error. I've also manually added the detail and `list_allowed_methods` to allow all forms POST/GET/ETC. I've Googled and overflowed to no avail! Help!

Here's the code I'm using for POSTING (I'm new to RestKit so be gentle)

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/"]];
RKObjectMapping *lotRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[lotRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"status" : @"parking_availability"}];
RKResponseDescriptor *lotResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:lotRequestMapping
                                                                                      pathPattern:@"parkinglot/:primaryKey/"
                                                                                          keyPath:nil
                                                                                      statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Screenshot - 
[image: xcode RestKit Code]

Here's the Error
See Screenshot
[image: 501 Not Implemented Xcode Error]

Text from Screenshot

> 2012-12-19 13:23:26.145 Parkable[36586:4b07] I
>   restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:143 POST
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/parkinglot/22/?format=json' 2012-12-19
>   13:23:26.158 Parkable[36586:3807] E
>   restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:156 POST
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/parkinglot/22/?format=json' (501 Not
>   Implemented): Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011
>   "Expected status code in (200-299,400-499), got 501"
>   UserInfo=0x9170260
>   {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/parkinglot/22/?format=json>,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/parkinglot/22/?format=json,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299,400-499), got
>   501,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=} 2012-12-19 13:23:26.158 Parkable[36586:4b07] E
>   restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:271 Object request failed:
>   Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error
>   Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in
>   (200-299,400-499), got 501" UserInfo=0x9470f10
>   {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/parkinglot/22/?format=json>,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/parkinglot/22/?format=json,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299,400-499), got
>   501,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=} 2012-12-19 13:23:26.159 Parkable[36586:c07] failure -
>   Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code
>   in (200-299,400-499), got 501" UserInfo=0x9470f10
>   {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/parkinglot/22/?format=json>,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/parkinglot/22/?format=json,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299,400-499), got
>   501,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question the 501 error went away after adding in the

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
```

to the resources.py file and registering it with urls.py

```
v1_api.register(UserResource())
```